# What is the distance of a particular root to the farthest one with respect to it as a function of a compacting factor?

Tags: real-analysis, na.numerical-analysis, norms, rootfinding

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined as

$$f := 2a_{1}(x - x^{p}) + 2a_{2}(x - x^{p})\sum_{k \in K}||x_{k} - x^{p}_{k}||^{2} + \dfrac{2a_{3}}{\alpha}\sum_{j \in J}\dfrac{\frac{1}{\alpha}(x - x^{p})||x - x^{p}||^{\frac{1}{\alpha}-2}||x - x_{j}|| - 2(x - x_{j})||x - x^{p}||^\frac{1}{\alpha}}{||x - x_{j}||^{4}},$$

where $\{a_{i}\mid 1 \le i \le 3\}$ are positive constant numbers. $x^{p}$ is a constant vector, and sets $J$ and $K$ are two (not-necessarily-disjoint) index sets. $\alpha$ is a positive number which may be chosen from range $[1,\infty).$

Let $Z$ be the set of the roots of the equation $f(x) = 0_{2\times1}$, say, $Z:= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid f(x) = \mathbf{0}\}$. Note that the only immediately-detectable element of $Z$ is $x=x^{p}$. Define measure $d : = \max\limits_{z \in Z}||z - x^{P}||$ which represents the distance between $x = x^{p}$ and the farthest root with respect to it.

One observes that if $\alpha$ tends to infinity, then the third term of $f$ eventually vanishes, thereby remaining only $x = x^{p}$. It implies that sweeping $\alpha$ to larger values in fact decreases the value of measure $d$. In other words, each value of $\alpha$ compacts the roots of $f$ around $x = x^{p}$ in a circular region whose radius is $d$.

> **Question:** Let $d^{\star}$ correspond to $\alpha = 1$. Then, given a desired $0 < d < d^{\star}$, what is the largest $\alpha$
>   corresponding to it?